# How to use TimeCode.Filter?

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm-2015

I'm working with [TimeCode enumeration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.crm.sdk.messages.timecode.aspx) and I'd like to explore the one that relates to 3 (which is the next-to-last, for some weird reason in the table).

```
QueryScheduleRequest request = new QueryScheduleRequest
{
  ResourceId = user.Id,
  Start = DateTime.UtcNow,
  End = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(3.5),
  TimeCodes = new[] { TimeCode.Available, TimeCode.Unavailable,TimeCode.Filter }
};
```

I've googled my donkey off but I can't find any examples on how to specify the exact conditions for the filter (there's nothing sounding right amongst the properties of *QueryScheduleRequest* initializer.

Anybody with better google-fu or experience with filtering by time codes?

Comment: I'm not clear what you are asking - are you trying to figure out what the TimeCode.Filter value does?  I agree that public documentation of this value is minimal (I couldn't figure it out either).  If you have time, I would write up some test code, trying out different values and seeing what changes as you swap in and out values for TimeCodes.

Comment: @JosephDuty That'd be great. I kind of let that one go because of the poor documentation. But I think that there's certain need for some short examples. And you'll definitely be rewarded with some cool rep, hehe.